# Is there a better way of returning async data without promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, youtube-api

I have this function that should return only the raw statistics from a youtube channel using the youtube v3 data api

```js
var getChannelStats = function (chId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        google.youtube("v3").channels.list({
            key: token,
            part: "statistics",
            id: chId,
        }).then(res => {
            resolve(res.data?.items?.[0]?.statistics)
        })
    })
};
```

And then I want to have multiple functions to only return a certain information from the stats

```js
async function getChannelViews(channelId) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        getChannelStats(channelId).then(res => { resolve(res.viewCount) })
    })
}
```

Is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: You are using the promise constructor unnecessarily - don't create a promise when you already have one. `getChannelViews` should just return `getChannelStats(...)` and `getChannelStats` should just return `google.youtube(...).channels.list(....)`

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)

Comment: @Yousaf also, `getChannelViews` probably shouldn't be `async`. Or if it is, it could at least use `await` in the body: `const res = await getChannelStats(channelId); return res.viewCount;`

Comment: I guess you could just do `const getChannelViews = async (channelId) => (await getChannelStats(channelId)).viewCount`

Comment: try await keyword since you are already using async keyword

Comment: @VLAZ yes, you are right. There's lots of unnecessary promise creation in OP's code.

Comment: Thanks I tried using await but forgot the brackets around the await
I ended up using:
`
const getChannelViews = async (channelId) => { return (await getChannelStats(channelId)).viewCount }
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can chain `.then()` to something, in general it means it's already a Promise. So, there's no need wrapping that Promise inside another Promise, and resolve the outer Promise when the inner Promise resolves, it's overkill and inelegant.

Besides, instead of using `.then()`, it's easier to use `await` :

```
const getChannelStats = async (chId) => {
    const res = await google.youtube("v3").channels.list({
        key: token,
        part: "statistics",
        id: chId,
    })

    return res.data?.items?.[0]?.statistics // This is a Promise. Async functions always return Promises. So you can do await getChannelStats()
}

const getChannelViews = async (channelId) => (await getChannelStats(channelId)).viewCount;

const viewsCount = await getChannelViews(someChannelId);
console.log("viewsCount = ", viewsCount);
```